# Haskell Lambda help - Creating a applications function

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I am trying to create a function **applications** that will, when given a term N and a list of terms (X1,...,Xn) return N(X1,...,Xn)

But when I run my code, it shows the following error:

```
    * Couldn't match type `Term' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: Var
        Actual type: Term
    * In the first argument of `Lambda', namely `x'
      In the expression: Lambda x (applications v xs)
      In an equation for `applications':
          applications v (x : xs)
            | x == [] = Lambda x v
            | otherwise = Lambda x (applications v xs)
    |
147 |     |otherwise = Lambda x (applications v xs)
```

But for some reason my **applications** function causes this error, even though it seems similar to my working **abstractions**.

```
applications :: Term -> [Term] -> Term
applications v [] = v
applications v (x:xs)
    |x == [] = Lambda x v
    |otherwise = Lambda x (applications v xs)
```

I would appreciate any help as I am new to this!

Comment: Well in your `applications` you pass a list of `Term`s, your `Lambda` likely expects a `Var` as item in the head? Furthermore it should be `null xs` instead of `x == []` I guess, although that is likely not the "core problem".

Comment: `applications` is also the opposite of `abstractions` based on the description here. Here you should basically pattern match on `Lambda`, and then replace the variable in the head of the lambda in the body of the lambda with the term.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that has helped. My code now reads: 
    |null xs = Lambda x v
   Although I am now getting an error on the line : |otherwise = Lambda x (applications v xs)

Comment: yes, because as said, you can not use a `Term` as variable in your `Lambda`. Furthermore `applications` should do the *opposite* of `abstractions`.

Comment: You don't want to use `Lambda` to build an application. There are no lambdas in your description of what you want to do: "given a term N and a list of terms (X1,...,Xn) return N(X1,...,Xn)". Usually there's a `Term` constructor for application.

Comment: Yes this makes sense now, thank you for the help. @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your type `Term` is defined as follows:

```
type Var  = String
data Term = Var Var | Lambda Var Term | App Term Term deriving Show
```

That is, that application is captured by a binary data constructor `App`.

Now, note that your definition of `abstractions` can be simplified by dropping the case distinction from the second clause (the case for an empty tail is caught by the first clause already):

```
abstractions :: Term -> [Var] -> Term
abstractions t []       = t
abstractions t (x : xs) = Lambda x (abstractions t xs)
```

Where lambda-abstractions typically extend as far to the right as possible, i.e.,  *lambda x1. lambda x2. t = lambda x1. (lambda x2. t)*, function application typically associates to the left, i.e., *t u1 u2 = (t u1) u2*. Hence, a straightforward application of your function `applications` could be:

```
applications :: Term -> [Term] -> Term
applications t []       = t
applications t (u : us) = applications (App t u) us
```

For example:

```
> applications (Var "x") [Var "y", Var "z"]
App (App (Var "x") (Var "y")) (Var "z")
```

Now, finally, `abstractions` and `applications` follow familiar patterns. `abstractions` can be written as a right-fold over a list of variables to abstract over and `applications` can be written as a left-fold over a list of terms to apply to:

```
abstractions = foldr Lambda
applications = foldl App
```

Comment: This was a brilliant help. Getting the hang of it more now. Thanks.